# Copy & Paste the Selected text from the PDF File using AXAcroPDF in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, copy, itext, clipboard-interaction

[image: Code][image: windows image]I have a windows form in VB.net having the following tools

1. Adobe pdf Reader(AxAcroPDF)
2. A Text box
3. Two Buttons

On Clicking the first button ,the pdf file selected using Open dialog box will appear on AxAcroPDF.
I Want to SELECT a desired text from the  pdf shown and then to display this text to the text box(Copy & Paste Method) on the click event of the second button.
I cannot find the AxAcroPDF.Selectedtext property.I searched a lot and also tried to use iTextSharp to accomplish it.But failed.
Please Help !

Comment: I don't have the answer for your specific question but I have a code that extracts the entire text from a pdf if you want.

Comment: I actualy want to copy the selected text from the pdf

Comment: Consider adding some images to your post that illustrate what you're describing. Also, provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) which shows what you've already tried.

Comment: I have added the image of window and code to the post .Please note and check. The portion of the code to be worked  strText = PdfTextExtractor.Clipboard(reader2, 2, its) is not working